# Fetching the value from json

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am querying DNS to check MX records of the given domain and getting following response-:

I'm using Google Apps script `UrlFetchApp` class for this, now what I want is to create an array that will have only the values of MX records-:
(e.g -: [20 mx2.zoho.com, 30 mx3.zoho.com, 10 mx.zoho.com]

how can i do that?
thank you for your help.

so far, I am here

```
function mxLookup() {

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("domains")
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
      var apiurl = "https://dns-api.org/MX/";

      for (i=1; i<data.length; i++){
        var domain = data[i][0]
        var url = apiurl+domain
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
        var json = JSON.parse(response);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above is not exactly wrong, but it won't work in with Apps Script because of the ES6 syntax.

You can write it with the map function as below:

```
var arr = json.map(function(each) {
  return each.value;
});

Logger.log(arr);
```

You can use the ES6 syntax in .html files in an apps script project, however, you can't use it yet in the .gs files.

Comment: thank you, so far am here, not sure how to get all MX values
function mxLookup() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("domains")
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var apiurl = "https://dns-api.org/MX/";
  
  for (i=1; i<data.length; i++){
    var domain = data[i][0]
    var url = apiurl+domain
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
    var json = JSON.parse(response)

Comment: So just use my code directly below yours. That maps your `json` array into the variable `arr` as you asked for in your original question.

Comment: thank you @jordan it worked. do you recommend any reference material to understand it, am kind of newbie. –

Comment: the `map` method is a javascript array method. It takes each element into a function and returns a new array. Here is the documentation with a good explanation and examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

It's a perfect use-case for using `map` (thanks @Łukasz).

```js
const
  inputArray = [
     {
        "ttl" : 3600,
        "type" : "MX",
        "value" : "20 mx2.zoho.com.",
        "name" : "domainname.com"
     },
     {
        "name" : "domainname.com",
        "value" : "30 mx3.zoho.com.",
        "type" : "MX",
        "ttl" : 3600
     },
     {
        "ttl" : 3600,
        "name" : "domainname.com",
        "value" : "10 mx.zoho.com.",
        "type" : "MX"
     }
  ],
  mxValues = inputArray.map(item => item.value),
  mxValues2 = [];

  for (var index=0; index<inputArray.length; index++) {
      mxValues2.push(inputArray[index].value);
  }
  
  console.log(mxValues);
  console.log(mxValues2);
```

Comment: Or just map: const mxValues = inputArray.map(entry => entry.value);

Comment: (cough) of course, map... how could I forget about map? (cough)

Comment: thank you, it does not work when i try in Google Apps Script editor.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Google Apps Script editor. It could also be your browser, what browser do you use? It can also be solved without `.map()` with a `for` loop.

Comment: I've updated my answer from my phone, can't see if the modification works. I hope it does or that the edit is at least good enough to get you going.

Comment: @Thijs, @Gela Ram Your script is not wrong for the result. But at Google Apps Script (GAS), ES6 cannot be used yet. So your script can be modified for GAS as follows. 1. Modify arrow function from ``mxValues = inputArray.map(item => item.value),`` to ``mxValues = inputArray.map(function(item){return item.value})``. 2. Modify ``console.log()`` to ``Logger.log()``.